# Changing font size in Text Mode terminal

Tags: linux, terminal

I have Ubuntu working in TEXT mode. I would like to change the font size (or if possible, get my terminal with inconsolata font). How can I do this?

PS: I don't have a GUI or X Windows running.

Answer (score 8):

`sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` did the trick

Answer (score 5):

The [Linux Cookbook](http://dsl.org/cookbook/cookbook_20.html) says

> Console fonts are stored in the `/usr/share/consolefonts` directory as compressed files; to install new console fonts, have the system administrator make a `/usr/local/share/consolefonts` directory and put the font files in there.

Use `consolechars` to set the current console font; give the base file name of a console font as an argument to the `-f' option.

To set the console font to the scrawl_w font, type:

> consolechars -f scrawl_w [RET]

Some font files contain more than one height (or size) of the font. If a font contains more than one encoding for different heights, give the height to use as an argument to the `-H' option. (If you try to do it without the option anyway, consolechars will output a list of available sizes.)

Common console font heights include 8 (for 8x8 fonts), 14 (for 8x14 fonts), and 16 (for 8x16 fonts).

To set the console font to the 8x8 size sc font, type:

> $ consolechars -H 8 -f sc [RET]

To list all of the characters in the current console font, type:

> $ showcfont [RET]

Comment: unfortunately i don't have the command consolechars. `sudo dpkg-reconfigure console-setup` did the trick.